# Google indexes partially translated pages in preference to original ones

Tags: seo, translation, localization

We have a website translated in 6 different languages. Our client translates the pages itself.

There are 2 different kinds of contents translated:

- static ones (like buttons and messages)
- dynamic ones (the contents that our client can change)

All that static contents have been translated in the 6 languages

But on a webpage, if dynamic contents are not translated, we fallback to other languages (if no Spanish is available, try English, then French if no English is available)

That leads at some pages with contents in different languages (like [this one](https://stationdetrail.com/it/stations/haut-bugey-montagnes-du-jura/destinations/nantua) which contains Italian navigation, but with dynamic contents not been translated in Italian). **When we search on Google, this page comes before the French one** (my browser and Google is set to French).

How could we avoid that?

Comment: Have you tried using noindex tags on the partially translated pages?

Comment: After looking for awhile yesterday, I did that. It's a good start. Thank you for your comment, it could be an answer!

Comment: Yes, noindex can be a good thing to do. Also block those pages at robots.txt so that Google won't access it.